# What alternative for ArrayList using JAX-WS?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

I'm using JAX-WS and i need to export a method that returns an **ArrayList of Object**, the issue is that **JAX-WS** doesn't support **ArrayList**.
my question is "Is there way to send my Objects ?"

NB : i'm not using any Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, i just changed the return type of the method to **MyObject[]**, since jax-ws accepts this type of returns.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type from ArrayList to java.util.List.

Comment: didn't work neither, it only accepts array of objects, for example: User[] array = new User[10];